# SQL get MAX in ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, max

I whant to get **MAX** value of some column in **ORDER BY** sentence, how can I do this?

I tried this, and somehow instrad of ordering values, it it returned only one row insted. What is wrong here?

```
ORDER BY (
     CASE WHEN LEFT(mobile_plans_prices.free_minutes,  1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' 
          THEN mobile_plans_prices.free_minutes+0  
          ELSE MAX(mobile_plans_prices.free_minutes) 
     END
)
```

Note: this code supposed to sort strings as numbers(when they are) and put strings in the back

Comment: When you say "this code supposed to sort strings as numbers(when they are) and put strings in the back" what does that have to do with putting the highest value in that column into the order by clause? If you just order by free_minutes it should sort the data by that column, showing numbers ascending first, and then letters ascending second, which sounds like it's what you want.

Comment: I don't think `ORDER BY` clause can filter your query. It is only responsible for ordering. I don't believe this as long as I can't see the problem replicated, in http://sqlfiddle.com maybe. Suspect other parts before `ORDER BY` part, it is least likely to be source of your problem *in my opinion*.

Comment: You need to show the rest of the query to get this answered.

Comment: Without seeing proper DDLs and sample data, I don't think we're going to be able to help. That said, there are some pretty clever people here, verging on psychic, if you ask me - so, you never know.